# Strange Reduction of Rational Expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This question was recently posed to me, and I was stumped partially because I had done rational expressions in my past but I don't think I ever solved ones like this:

$$ \frac{6m^{2}-2m-10}{9-m^{2}} \times \frac{m^{2}-6m+9}{6m^{2}+29m-20} $$

I could reduce it down to the expression below thanks to working on the first term denominator and second term numerator:

$$ \neg \frac{m-3}{3+m} \times \frac{6m^{2}-2m-10}{6m^{2}+29m-20} $$

But from there I couldn't deduce a path. I feel like I'm missing something fairly obvious but I hope this question can still be of use to others. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have got
$$\frac{2(3m^2-m-5)(m-3)^2}{-(m-3)(m+3)(6m^2+29m-20)}=-\frac{2(3m^2-m-5)(m-3)}{(m+3)(6m^2+29m-20)}$$

Comment: I got close to this answer, was missing the 2 being pulled out. I couldn't find a way to reduce past your answer so I guess this is the simplest it gets? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Compute the real roots of all four quadratic polynomials to factor them as products $a(x-r_0)(x-r_1)$ and simplify what can be. The trinomials with quadratic roots can't be simplified as they have no root in common.